# e-Tex and TexWriter

Tags: etoolbox, e-tex

I'm using [TexWriter](http://www.texwriterapp.com/) as a LaTeX editor on my iPad. When I try to compile a document I get the following error:"!package etoolbox Error: Not running under e-TeX." 
I'm also using `enumitem` package.
Is there a way to get around this?

Comment: If TeX Writer doesn't use e-TeX, you lose out on a lot of the newer packages, including `etoolbox` (and packages which depend on it, such as `biblatex`).  Until TeX Writer enables the e-TeX extensions, you are out of luck....

Comment: I'd suggest to ask at the TeXWriter forum, see: http://www.litchie.com/forum/viewforum.php?f=13

Comment: @bozidarka have you asked?

Comment: On iPad the Texpad app supports eTeX

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that TeXWriter is based on a very minimal TeX distribution that only uses Knuth TeX, which doesn't have the e-TeX extensions necessary to run a bunch of modern packages (notably `biblatex` and its toolkit `etoolbox`).

Unless the developers of that TeX distribution get convinced to add e-TeX, you're out of luck.

Comment: At our lab, we have discovered this same issue with Scientific Workplace.